# Javascript toLowerCase() undefined error

Tags: javascript

I know this has been put out too many times, but none of the questions fix the problem I have. It gives me the following error every time I run the function:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

Here's the code it's running:

```
global.toId = function(text) {
    return text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
};
```

Comment: Its because variable `text` in your method is undefined. You should check for undefined, see this previous SO question: [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: Igor is correct. Where is the `text` parameter coming from when you call it? Can we see more of the code?

Comment: Check the invocation of toId function. You call it with undefined argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a protection with:

```
if(typeof text === 'string')
```

In the function:

```
global.toId = function(text) {
   if(typeof text === 'string')
      return text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
   else
      console.log('incorrect input');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In ES2020, you can use optional chaining (?.)

```
global.toId = function(text) {
    return text?.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this help you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

    <body>

        <script>

            var str = "EHSAN";

            var toId  = function(text) {

            return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, '');

            }

           alert(toId());

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```